# celery issue! [Flask+Celery+redis] [2021-06-07 12:31:18,849: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

This is the error code I got:

```
[2021-06-07 12:27:52,535: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'fashion.views.json_update.json_update'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
b'[[2], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (78b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 581, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'fashion.views.json_update.json_update'
```

I've been trying to make APIs using `Flask, Flask-sqlAlchemy, Blueprint, Application Factory`. And for last three days, I've been trying to add `celery+redis`, and it's not working. I guess it is mainly due to `path` and `application instance`.

My working directories looks like:

```
# These are the folders and files that I currently using celery for.

-- back
  -- fashion
    -- __init__.py
    -- models.py
    -- address_format.py
    -- error_code.py
    ...
    -- views
       -- cardgame.py
       -- json_update.py
       ...
```

The whole process are like this:
If Front-end sends POST request for 'maincard' API from `cardgame.py`, it invokes `json_update` function from `json_update.py`(which makes json file) while it saves some info from Front-end to mySQL db.
`__init__.py` has celery instance.

And my `__init__.py` looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from flask_jwt_extended import (JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token,
                                get_jwt_identity, unset_jwt_cookies, create_refresh_token)
import pymysql
from flask_cors import CORS
# import config

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(__name__, broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost:3306/fashion'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
     
    # ORM
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
    from .views import auth, main, cardgame, share, bookmark, details
    app.register_blueprint(cardgame.bp)
    ...

    jwt = JWTManager(app)
    bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

    return app
```

`models.py`:

```
from fashion import db
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, DateTime, Column, Integer, String, DATE, Text, func, Boolean, Float, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
...
```

`cardgame.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import Flask, request

...

from fashion import models

...

from fashion import error_code
from fashion import address_format

...

from fashion.views.json_update import json_update

bp = Blueprint('cardgame', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@bp.route('/maincard', methods=['GET','POST'])
@jwt_required()
def maincard():
    if request.method =='GET':
        ...
    else: 
        if not request.is_json:
            return error_code.missing_json_error
        else:
            body=request.get_json()
            user_id = get_jwt_identity()
     
            ...

            json_update.delay(user_id)

            ...

            return {
                    'result': result
                    }, 200
```

`json_update.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import Flask, request
...
from fashion import models
...
from fashion import error_code
from fashion import address_format
... 

from fashion.__init__ import celery


@celery.task(bind=True)
def json_update(self, user_id):
    ...
    return{
        'result':'succeed'
    }
```

And these are versions of libraries:

```
celery==5.1.0
Flask==2.0.0
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-JWT-Extended==4.2.1
Flask-Migrate==2.7.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
redis==3.5.3
SQLAlchemy==1.4.15
vine==5.0.0
virtualenv==20.4.6
```

Also we are using Docker, Linux environment.

Comment: I am running into a similar issue using plotly dash 2.0.0, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Kyle Sadly no...;(

Comment: @Kyle, I'm having the same issue with Dash 2. They might be working on it in https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1769.